# Moving codefolds in Vim

Tags: vim

I have the following two code folds:

[image]

How would I move the bottom code fold above the top one? Is there a shortcut for that?

Comment: How about `ddP`?

Comment: *"StackOverflow disallows me posting a question with the word 'code' in it for some reason"* LOL that's just silly.

Comment: Was there any particular problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: I agree that not allowing "code" is strange... workarounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can operate on a fold as a whole as if you're operating on a single line. So simply using `dd` here will cut the whole folded block.

See [`:help fold-behavior`](https://vimhelp.org/fold.txt.html#fold-behavior):

> [...] When using an operator, a closed fold is included as a whole. Thus `dl` deletes the whole closed fold under the cursor.

Comment: thanks for this. Out of curiosity, why would `dl` work here? I thought `l` was letter, so is the fold treated as a single character/unit, or how does that end up working?

Comment: Yes, `dl` deletes a single character. That's the point, the whole folded block "looks" like a single character, in the sense that it's "indivisible" (while folded.) I hope that makes sense to you...

Comment: it seems like you have to re-create the fold afterwards though, as when you copy/paste it in, the code is unfolded and hitting `za` says no fold found.

Comment: @David542 Depends largely on your `'foldmethod'` though... But yes, sometimes you need to recreate it, particularly if you're using manual folds.